# Let $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be a $C^3$ map then we have $f(a+x)=f(a)+\lambda x+\mu(x)x^2$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be a $C^3$ map and $V$ be a neighbourhood of the critical points of $f.$ Then if $a\in [0,1]\setminus V$ we have $f(a+x)=f(a)+\lambda x+\mu(x)x^2,$ where

$|\lambda|\geq\min\{|Df(x)|; \; x\in[0,1]\setminus V\}$ and  $\mu$ is differentiable and
$$\max\{|\mu(x)|, |D\mu(x)|;\; x\in [0,1]\setminus V\}<\infty.$$

This is a special case of Taylor or Lagrange Theorem?

Comment: I don't see why the inequality is strict.  For example, choose $a\in[0,1]-V$ minimising $\lvert f'(a)\rvert$ and you are forced to have $\lambda=f'(a)$ which doesn't satisfy $\lvert\lambda\rvert>\min_{x\in[0,1]-V}\lvert f'(x)\rvert$.

Comment: Sorry! The correct is $\lambda\geq \min\{|Df(x)|; x\in [0,1]\setminus V\}.$